# Running a php55-runtime app with dev_appserver.py in a Docker container or on macOS Ventura

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

Has anyone here by any chance managed to get Google Cloud SDK's development server `dev_appserver.py` running a **php55-runtime** based app in a Docker container (or macOS Ventura)?

I'm working on a few App Engine projects that were set up years ago on the now-legacy php55 runtime (**1st gen standard environment**). I know the runtime is heading towards its end-of-support date. However, before the work of migrating everything to PHP8 on these projects begins, there are some urgent little modifications that need to be done on the php55-runtime projects.

I used to take care of these kind of needs with an old MacBook that had a not-so-recent version of the **Google Cloud SDK** for macOS (including **python2**) -- which allowed running php55-runtime apps locally with the development server `dev_appserver.py` before deployment. The SDK included a pre-built PHP 5.5.x binary for macOS back then.

Nowadays I'm using a newer MacBook and I was imagining I could set up a Docker container to handle the dev_appserver.py & gcloud CLI stuff (deployment) using the `google/cloud-sdk:alpine` image. For PHP7/8 based 2nd gen standard environment apps that seems to work, but to get a php55-runtime based app running with dev_appserver.py seems like an uphill struggle, because in addition to needing python2 in the container (which I managed to install using an older alpine-based SDK image), you also need to build the PHP 5.5.x binaries (including Google's PHP extension if I understand correctly) as they are not included in the Google Cloud SDK's Linux version. I haven't managed to compile the old PHP version on a recent alpine or debian Docker container.

Has anyone out there managed to make all this happen or does anyone have other workarounds they've discovered that make running old php55-runtime apps on the development server still possible either in a Docker container or directly on macOS Ventura?

One can of course install the Google Cloud SDK directly on macOS without messing around with Docker, but you'd need to somehow install python2 for dev_appserver.py and the SDK's macOS version doesn't seem to include the php55 runtime binaries anymore.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: ...after some battles, I finally managed to get this working using a modified Dockerfile from [hariri/docker-google-appengine-php](https://github.com/mhariri/docker-google-appengine-php). I'm now able to run a php55-runtime based app in a Docker container with the development server (dev_appserver.py) included in SDK 441.0 (PHP 5.5.38 & the Google PHP extension compiled in the Docker image).